# Como criar cores hexadecimais aleatoriamente?

Tags: php, html, css, hexadecimal

Como eu posso criar o código das cores em *hexadecimal* randomicamente com PHP?

Por exemplo, do `#000000` ao `#FFFFFF`, para gerar algo parecido com isso:

```
<div style="color: <?= rand_color()?>">
     Estou colorido!
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma forma alternativa de realizar essa tarefa, é criar um array contendo os valores válidos para se criar uma cor em hexadecimal o intervalo é: 0-9A-F, isso é feito com [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) que cria dois arrays, um de 0 a 9 e outro de A a F, [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) faz combinação deles.

Por último um while simples verifica se a string já possui 7 caracteres(um sustenido seguido de seis alfanúmericos), do contrario, gera um número aleatório entre 0 e 15 que é usado como indíce em `$hex` que tem os valores válidos.

```
<?php
$hex = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'F'));

$cor = '#';
while(strlen($cor) < 7){
    $num = rand(0, 15);
    $cor .= $hex[$num];
}

echo $cor;
```

Answer (score 10):

Em php você pode fazer isso de maneira bem simples:

```
sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0XFFFFFF));
```

Explicando:

`#` é o caractere inicial utilizado para cores em hexadecimal em `HTML`

`%06` significa que os valores randomicos serão preenchidos com `0` até 6 vezes caso não chegue a 6 caracteres

O `X` de `%06X` é a formatação do `sprintf` que interpreta determinado valor como `hexadecimal`. Usamos nesse caso o `x` maiúsculo para gerar as letras do `hexadecimal` em maiúsculo também.

`mt_rand` se encarregará de gerar um  número aleatório desde `0` até `16777215`. O número `16777215` é proveniente da expressão hexadecimal `0xFFFFFF`.

#### Atualização

A partir do PHP 7, o PHP agora possui uma função chamada `random_int`.

É possível também utilizá-la:

```php
function random_color()
{
    return sprintf('#06x', random_int(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
```

Comment: Tendo em vista que `random_int` é criptograficamente seguro, pode ser um pouco mais lento que `mt_rand`. Além disso, como o objetivo é apenas para gerar uma _cor_ aleatória, deixo o questionamento: realmente vale a pena?

Answer (score 3):

No detalhamento da pergunta é solicitado uma solução em PHP, mas geralmente PHP roda em ambientes web, partindo desse pré-suposto você não necessáriamente precisa executar isso em PHP.

Em certos casos precisamos avaliar se realmente vale a pena dar ao servidor a tarefa de algo tão simplório que pode ser executado no lado do cliente, como por exemplo dar cor a algo na interface HTML.

O processamento do lado do cliente é melhor porque você não sabe se os recursos do lado do servidor estão livres e ele poderá facilmente lidar com as solicitações. Mas o envio de grandes quantidades de dados ao cliente para processamento incorrerá em sobrecarga do cliente e tornará sua experiência de navegação menos aceitável, imagine requisitar ao servidor para cada cor? A rede pode ficar sobrecarregada e a largura de banda consumida. O processamento de dados no lado do servidor aumentará a carga do servidor a cada novo cliente.

Portanto, para evitar esses problemas, é melhor primeiro transferir alguns desses conflitos para o lado do cliente já que elementos de cor não devem ser problemas de segurança.

Além disso, estou presumindo  que o JavaScript está ativado.

Uma solução com javascript seria usar funções matemáticas aleatórias como por exemplo:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
```

## Exemplo de uso

```js
for(let i=0;i<=60;i++){
 document.write('<div data-randcolor>  Estou colorido!</div>');
}


let randHexColor = () => {
  return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}


window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  let randColor = document.querySelectorAll('[data-randcolor]');
  randColor.forEach((elm) => {
    elm.style.color = randHexColor();
   });
});

// Discoteca
setInterval(()=>{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randHexColor();
  let randColor = document.querySelectorAll('[data-randcolor]');
  randColor.forEach((elm) => {
    elm.style.color = randHexColor();
   });
},500);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;  
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
  background-color: #000;
}
div {
display:block;
width: 100%;
}
```

## Orquestrando e executando javascript com PHP

A pergunta é sobre PHP e tem várias formas que já postaram por aqui e todas são válidas.
Gostaria de apresentar uma vertente um pouco conhecida que é a execução de scripts javascript v8 nativamente pelo PHP.

Esse caso pode ser usado por exemplo para implementar um micro-serviços em Javascript orquestrados por um motor PHP que agrega tudo.

É possível rodar javascript com PHP utilizando a [extensão
V8js](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.v8js.php) que executa um motor v8 do javascript nativamente no PHP para interpretá-lo.

```
<?php

$v8 = new V8Js();

/* basic.js */
$JS = <<< EOT
let randHexColor = () => {
  return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
} 
let len = print('Cor aleatória' + ' ' + randHexColor());
randHexColor();


EOT;

try {
  var_dump($v8->executeString($JS, 'basic.js'));
} catch (V8JsException $e) {
  var_dump($e);
}

?>
```

O Javascrip será executado pelo interpretador e você poderá obter a saida disso, todas as [funções do V8](https://v8.dev/features) estão disponíveis, o que faz você extender a funcionalidade do php à aquilo que talvez só esteja presente no V8.

## Alternativa PHP

Claro, rodar um motor V8 do Javascript pode parecer um tanto exagero para apenas gerar uma string aleatória e talvez você esteja em um ambiente que não é executado nada no cliente como por exemplo a linha de comando ou então uma API REST.
A Abordagem é sempre a mesma, alguma função matemática para gerar a string e é justamente o que a função [mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php) faz, gera números aleatórios, nesse caso hexadecimais aleatórios:

```
<?php 
printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF ));
?>
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta! Processar do lado do servidor isso é bobeira (claro, de acordo com os requisitos da questão ele pergunta por PHP) mas sem dúvidas é a melhor resposta.

Comment: Até entendo a preocupação de executar no client-side para não gastar recursos do server-side a toa. Essa parte de resposta está ótima. Porém a parte de usar V8, acho um exagero. Eu ainda ficaria só com as funções nativas do PHP mesmo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi apenas por curiosidade, já que estava falando de javascript e php.

Answer (score 0):

Há diversas formas de resolver este problema.

```
$aleatorio = mt_rand(0, 16777215);
$cor = "#" . dechex($aleatorio);
```

Depois, assumindo que pretendes alterar a cor de fundo do tag `div`, adicionar:

```
background-color: <?php echo $cor ?>;
```