# Qual é a diferença entre as funções rand, mt_rand, random_int?

Tags: php, números-aleatórios

Para gerar números aleatórios com PHP, existe algumas funções. Dentre elas `rand`, e `mt_rand`.

Até pouco tempo atrás, eu utilizava o `mt_rand`, pois como a documentação diz, ela é um [*"gerador melhorado de números aleatórios"*](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand). Por exemplo, utilizei essa função nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103366/4995).

Porém, o PHP 7 agora possui também a função chamada de `random_int`, que segundo a documentação:

> [...] Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers.

Diante de tantas opções de geração de números aleatórios, eu gostaria então de saber o seguinte:

- Quais são as principais diferenças entre essas funções funções?
- No caso de `mt_rand`, por que é considerada um *"gerador de números aleatórios melhorados"*?
- E a função `random_int`? Ela tem possui alguma melhoria em relação as demais?
- Em que caso de uso deveria utilizar cada uma delas?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026) e [O que é uma semente aleatória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104335/4995)

Comment: A partir do PHP 7.1, `rand` é um _alias_ para `mt_rand`. [Veja.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rand` e `mt_rand`, segundo a documentação ([aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) e [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)), não são consideradas criptograficamente seguras (para este propósito, recomenda-se o uso de [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php), sobre o qual falaremos mais abaixo).

Tanto `rand` quanto `mt_rand` funcionam de maneira similar: se forem chamadas sem parâmetros, retornam um número entre zero e um limite máximo (para `rand`, o limite é o número retornado por [`getrandmax`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php), e para `mt_rand`, o limite é o número retornado por [`mt_getrandmax`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php)).

Se forem chamadas com um parâmetro apenas, ambas dão um *warning* ("*expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given*" <- testei no PHP 7.3.6) e retornam `NULL`.

Se forem chamadas com 2 parâmetros (chamados de `$min` e `$max`), retornam um número entre `$min` e `$max`, lembrando que ambos são inclusos (em muitas linguagens o valor final não é incluso, então esse é um fator que costuma gerar muitos *off-by-one errors*).

Um detalhe "interessante" é que se `$min` for maior que `$max`, `rand` funciona, mas `mt_rand` não. Ou seja, `rand(5, 3)` retorna um número entre 3 e 5, mas `mt_rand(5, 3)` dá um *warning* ("*max(3) is smaller than min(5)*") e retorna `FALSE`.

Isso aconteceu no PHP 7.3.6 (versão que usei para testar), mesmo com a documentação dizendo que [a partir do PHP 7.1 `rand` se tornou um *alias* de `mt_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases). Esse comportamento é mencionado na [documentação de `rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

> *Note: As of PHP 7.1.0, `rand()` uses the same random number generator as `mt_rand()`. **To preserve backwards compatibility `rand()` allows max to be smaller than min as opposed to returning false as `mt_rand()`**.*

Aliás, no trecho acima temos outro detalhe: a partir do PHP 7.1 ambos usam o mesmo algoritmo, que no caso é o [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) (antes disso, `rand` usava o [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)).

---

Já `random_int` possui mais diferenças. A [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) cita que é uma função criptograficamente segura (e o *trade-off* é ela ser mais lenta), e além disso sempre deve ser chamada com 2 argumentos, indicando os valores mínimo e máximo. Outra diferença para `rand` e `mt_rand` é que se o máximo for menor que o mínimo, é lançado um [`Error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php).

Esta função lança um [`Exception`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) se não for encontrada uma fonte de *randomness* apropriada. Segundo a documentação, essa fonte varia conforme o ambiente:

- no Windows, para PHP >= 7.2.0 usa-se a [CNG-API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-portal), para outras versões usa-se [`CryptGenRandom`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- no Linux, usa-se a [*syscall* `getrandom(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html), se estiver disponível
- em outras plataformas, usa-se `/dev/urandom`
- se nenhuma destas for encontrada, lança um `Exception`

---

Sobre "ser criptograficamente seguro", veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449594) e [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). Mas basicamente, se você não está lidando com criptografia (por exemplo, [se só quer mudar a cor de fundo do seu site aleatoriamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103365/112052)), não precisaria usar `random_int`.

Answer (score 6):

Não entendo a fundo, mas o que vou dizer não está errado, então pode render uns pontinhos. :D

**Resumo:** use a `random_int` para tudo o que envolva segurança da informação (como transmissão e armazenamento de dados protegidos) e deixe para usar a `mt_rand` (preferencialmente, pois é a mais rápida) ou a `rand` (se performance não for um problema no seu caso) para todos os outros casos em que segurança/privacidade não forem preocupações.

Para qualquer coisa relacionada a criptografia e segurança da informação, encriptar, decriptar, gerar hashes, gerar salts, deve-se usar sempre um gerador "criptograficamente seguro", mesmo que em geral esses sejam os mais lentos. Isso porque se não tiver essa característica os mal-intencionados que estiverem de posse de alguns *samples* (amostras) de dados gerados a partir dele conseguem prever, estatisticamente, os números com maior probabilidade de serem gerados e têm mais chance de inutilizar a sua segurança. Portanto para esses casos sempre use essa `random_int` ou coisa melhor, caso surja futuramente.

Essa [mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php) pelo que entendi teve uma melhoria em relação a outros mas foi mais na questão da performance, usando o *"Mersenne Twister"*, por isso é considerada "melhorada". Mesmo sendo mais rápido que os que eram usados antes, esse gerador ainda não é considerado criptograficamente seguro, conforme diz a documentação linkada, então evite usar em situações criptográficas. Use para gerar números da mega-sena, jogadas de dados, qual carta tirar do baralho, essas coisas mais triviais.

E por fim o `rand` é o piorzinho de todos, não é criptograficamente seguro e também pode não ser performático. Mas para situações triviais acho que isso não deve ser muito impactante.

Por fim tem a questão de que é essencial que o gerador criptograficamente seguro seja bem "semeado" quando é inicializado (a "semente" ou "seed" é o valor inicial no qual o gerador se baseia para começar a gerar outros valores). Senão dá para prever o que vai ser gerado até sem precisar de amostras prévias, já que o algoritmo gerador por melhor que seja em geral não escapa de ser pseudo-aleatório e determinístico (aleatoriedade real depende de equipamento do qual as pessoas normalmente não dispõem em computadores comuns). Se a biblioteca já providencia essa "semeadura" pra você de maneira segura, ótimo, senão pode ser que você tenha que se informar como providenciar na mão.

Comment: Já que você citou ele, vou relacionar [O que é Mersenne Twister?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104329)