# Como gerar cores hexadecimais aleatórias com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cores

Nessa pergunta, ensina como [gerar cores aleatórias através do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103365/como-criar-cores-hexadecimais-aleat%c3%b3riamente).

Como fazer isso em JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em uma linha, dá para fazer assim:

```
'#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

Breve explicação da expressão acima:

- A função `Math.floor` arredonda o número para baixo, de modo a remover a parte decimal do número gerado pela função `Math.random`.
- O método `Number.prototype.toString(16)` converte o número em string em sua representação hexadecimal.
- O método `String.prototype.padStart(6, '0')` garante que a string hexadecimal tenha sempre seis dígitos.

E uma adaptação em JavaScript [desta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103376/69296):

```
let str = '#';
while (str.length < 7) {
  str += Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10).toString(16);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A **título de curiosidade** também é possível utilizar a [API de criptografia](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) para gerar números aleatórios.

Diferentemente dos outros métodos da API de criptografia, o método [`RandomSource.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) permite obter valores randômicos independente do contexto de segurança em que o código está sendo executado.

`RandomSource.getRandomValues()` aceita como parâmetro um objeto [`typedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) e preenche com números aleatórios e o retorna.

O método [TypedArray.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) aplica uma função a um acumulador e cada valor do array para reduzi-los a um único valor.

```js
let rgb = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(3))
          .reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.toString(16), "#");

console.log(rgb)
```

[Tabela de compatibilidade de `RandomSource.getRandomValues()`](https://caniuse.com/getrandomvalues)
[Math.random vs crypto.getRandom](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6433/0/mathrandom-vs-cryptogetrandom)

Comment: Muito legal, Augusto! +1 :) Mas deixarei o mesmo questionamento que deixei na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103366/69296): Tendo em vista que a API `crypto` foi feita para fins que requerem números criptograficamente seguros, será que é realmente necessário utilizar algo tão poderoso e, portanto, mais computacionalmente exigente para algo tão simplório como gerar uma cor aleatória? Sei que você sabe da resposta para essa pergunta, mas deixo isso para outras pessoas que podem não saber disso.

Answer (score -2):

```js
    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }

    function setRandomColor() {
      $("#colorpad").css("background-color", getRandomColor());
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorpad" style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color:#000">

</div>
<button onclick="setRandomColor()">Gerar Cor</button>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma explicação sobre o que o código faz?